# Run script after click on the link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I will summarize my question in a simple example , i start

I have two example pages when I make the demonstration

**01.html**

```
   <script> 
    var demo = 'X1'
    alert(demo);
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#cont").on("click","a", function ( e ) {
    history.pushState({}, '', $(this).attr("href"));
    $('body').load(this.href + " #bodyframe", function(){
    });
    event.preventDefault();
    }); 
    }); 
 </script>
    <body>
    <div id="bodyframe">
    page01<br><br>
    <div id="cont"><a href="02.html">next page</a></div>
    </div>
    </body>
```

**page 02**

```
<script>
var demo = 'X2'
alert(demo)
</script>
<body>
<div id="bodyframe">
page02
</div>
</body>
```

When I run the page 01, it shows the alert with the variable 'demo' value, but when I click on the link and the page two is loaded, the page two don't show me the alert.
In summarize, I need to run the script of the page 02 when I clicked the link and loaded the page since the function on click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the element you have assigned the click event to is removed. It gets removed along with `#cont`.

You should delegate the click event from the body instead:

```
$("body").on("click","#cont a", function ( e ) {
```

**Updated**

It seems you are only using the `#bodyframe` portion of what you are loading. You should load it without to get the script (as it is outside the bodyframe)

```
$('body').load(this.href, function(){
```

Comment: likewise the javascript page two is not running

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your javascript on page 02. You forgot to close both lines of code with semicolons (;). That is why the alert is not showing when page 02 is loaded.

```
<script>
var demo = 'X2';
alert(demo);
</script>
<body>
<div id="bodyframe">
page02
</div>
</body>
```